# Alamofire queue request if previous query is executing

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

When I send first request and then again I send a second request, Alamofire  cancels the first request and gives error as -999 Canceled on it.
What is the way to solve so that both request get processed?

So what I want to do is, user clicks on a button one request is sent, and before that request has completed user clicks on the button again. This behaviour cancels the earlier request, rather what I want it do is, when the button is clicked and the request is sent, it should check whether the previous request is completed or still running. If it is completed then the request should process normally but if the previous request is not completed it should wait for the request to complete and once that is completed this request should be sent

```
 self.alamoFireManager.request(request )
                    .responseJSON { response in

                        print(response.request)  // original URL request
                        print(response.response) // URL response
                        print(response.data)     // server data
                        print(response.result)   // result of response serialization
                        guard response.result.error == nil else {
                            // got an error in getting the data, need to handle it
                            print("error calling GET on page")
                            print(response.result.error!)
                            print("Failure")

                            if( response.result.error?.code == -999 )
                            {
                                print("Previous Query is still Executing")
                                return
                            }
```

Comment: So what I figured out till now that my alamofire manger is getting overwritten by the new request. So, i need to save it somehow. Can someone point me in the direction as to how to save it?

Comment: I made an array of alamofire managers, is that a good solution though?